# IIS Express fails binding to IP

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, iis, visual-studio-2013

I'm having trouble viewing my in-development websites on some remote devices like iPad, Nexus phone, etc. I'm using IIS Express. I've set up the bindings this way:

```
<site name="WebApplication1" id="7">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="d:\Programming\WebDotNet\WebApplication1\WebApplication1" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:64203:localhost" />
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:64203:aurora" />
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:64203:192.168.1.24" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

There are a couple of troubles, though.

The first binding (`http://localhost:64203/`), naturally, works only on my machine, but it works in every browser.

The second binding (`http://aurora:64203/`) works partially. It works in IE, Firefox, Opera 12, Safari for Windows (5.1.7). This holds true for my machine and another Windows machine. The URL, however, doesn't work in Chrome, Opera (27), or on any of my mobile devices. On Nexus 5 I've tried both Chrome and Firefox.

The third binding (`http://192.168.1.24:64203/`) fails to register:

```
C:\Program Files\IIS Express>iisexpress.exe /site:WebApplication1
Successfully registered URL "http://localhost:64203/" for site "WebApplication1" application "/"
Successfully registered URL "http://aurora:64203/" for site "WebApplication1" application "/"
Failed to register URL "http://192.168.1.24:64203/" for site "WebApplication1" application "/". Error description: The network location cannot be reached. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help. (0x800704d0)
```

Please help me resolve this issues, as I really need to test my websites on mobile devices.

P.S.: If this might be relevant, my router is Cisco EPC3925 EuroDocsis 3.0 2-PORT Voice Gateway and I've set static IPs internally for most of my machines.

Comment: (1) Is 192.168.1.24 same as localhost? (2) Please post the entire config file, (3) Try to disable the firewall, (4) Try another port than 64203.

Comment: (1) Localhost is never the same as an IP. But, yes, when I'm running locally, it's from the same computer as that IP points to. (2) Are there any specific parts that are important, as the config file contains some personal data. (3) Firewall was disabled all the way. If it wouldn't be, how could IE on another PC still get trough? (4) This is just a sample for this question, I've tried with 5 or 6 different projects at least, which means just as many different ports. No difference in how it works.

Comment: (1) Don't nitpick, (2) Not if it is free from clutter, (3) Nitpicking again?, (4) I was worried about your using a dynamic port, (5-new) What about [using host headers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) as alternate solution.

Comment: (1) Wasn't nitpicking. Using the IP instead of localhost isn't interchangeable even on my dev machine. I'm differentiating, because the problem might have something to do with that. (2) I'll try to clean it up and post it, but it might take a day or two. (3) I played with the firewall and when it was on, it didn't work on the other Windows PC. (4) Nope. VS2013 assigns a (seemingly) random port to each web project. I tried changing it, but it doesn't seem there's an issue with fighting for the port. (5) I'll look into that an report back. Thanks

Comment: If you are using VS, sometimes running it once as administrator solves problems.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that in a lot of comments, but unfortunately it didn't help. I'm starting to think it might have something to do with my network at home or some other setting on my computer.

Comment: Probably useless question: You can ping 192.168.1.24 from your computer?

Comment: Yes. From both windows PC and from my Android phone.

Comment: You could use a sniffer such as wireshark to monitor the network when IIS starts.

Comment: You can specify '<ip-address>:<port>:<host-name>' in 'applicationhost.config' (found in '\users\<username>\My Documents\IISExpress\Config'). You can specify multiple bindings there.

Comment: @LouisSomers That doesn't work. It throws this error: Failed to register URL "http://aurora:64203:192.168.1.24/" for site "Empire24" application "/". Error description: The network location cannot be reached. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help. (0x800704d0)```

Comment: Have you added aurora to your hosts file (at 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc')? Try adding a line '127.0.0.1 aurora' by opening notepad as administrator and then opening the hosts file (you will need to run as administrator in order to save the hosts file)

Comment: Yes, I did, but it didn't work. Even if it did, that would only fix the problem on my machine, where I can just use the localhost defaults anyway. I wanted to use this to test on my mobile devices. I could probably set something similar to hosts on my Android phone, but not on the iPad. In the end it was way too much playing around, so I decided to make a development stage on my server and have it actually be hosted.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?  I've been running fine with a setup here doing exactly this and after the Win10 Threashold 2 upgrade it's all broken and I cannot seem to fix it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063124/iisexpress-config-broken-after-win-10-threshold-2-upgrade

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34070198/binding-iisexpress-to-ip-address-failing

Comment: @Jammer: Your link actually helped me finally set up this on my network. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the `*:64203:aurora` binding is concerned, your mobile devices need DNS entries mapping `aurora` to your IP address (I'm assuming `192.168.1.24`).

For the `*:64203:192.168.1.24` binding, I wasn't able to reproduce the error exactly.  I would make sure you are running the command from and elevated (Administrator) command prompt.  Also, the error description leads towards a network related error, so make sure that your IP configuration is correct.